# Use ASP.net 2010 B to Ping an IP Address

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm trying to use a simple Ping technique to ping an IP Address. I have added `Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` to my web page and tried to simply create a button that once clicked ping an IP address.

The problem that I have is an error message that states `'System.Net.NetworkInformation' is a namespace and cannot be used as an expression.`

I'm new to this and have tried to replace this with something else, but I still cannot seem to get this to work.  Would it be possible for someone to review this and let me know where I'm going wrong.  Im using VB and VS2010. This is my code:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping

Partial Class Ping
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Protected Sub btnPing_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPing.Click

    Using System.Net.NetworkInformation

        Ping(Ping = New Ping())
        PingReply(pingReply = Ping.send("xxx.xx.xxx.xx"))

        Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", pingReply.address)
        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", pingReply.Status)

    End Using

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx

Comment: The `Using System.Net.NetworkInformation` statement is wrong as you are trying to "use" a namespace - which you can't. I'm not sure what it should be replaced with (if anything)

Comment: @ChrisF,  If i remove the 'Using System.Net.NetworkInformation' from the btnPing_Click event. Every Ping item in the btnPing_Click code has the blue highlighlited line underneath it with an error message that states 'Ping is a type and cannot be used as an expression'.  this is the same message for 'PingReply'.

Comment: I don't know - I don't use vb.net that often so I couldn't say what the syntax should be,

Comment: @ChrisF, not a problem.  Many thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be better off trying the following:

Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

```
Partial Class Ping
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Protected Sub btnPing_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPing.Click
        Dim vPing As New Ping
        Dim vPingReply As PingReply = vPing.Send("xxx.xx.xxx.xx")
        Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", vPingReply.Address)
        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", vPingReply.Status)
End Sub
```

`System.Net.NetworkInformation` is just a namespace, it just serves as a container for other classes.

Comment: May thanks that makes sense about the container for other classes.  If i try your above code sample i get an error on the 'vPingReply.Send' section.  I get the normal blue line under the item and a message when i hover over that states 'Send is not a member of System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply'.  I have added Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply to the top of my page but i still have an error?

Comment: The 'vPingReply' object is used by calling the 'vPing.Send' method. I updated the code to clarify it.

Comment: many thanks this seems to have resolved the issue once i have created a property for object Send.

Answer (score 1):

You've named your page class `Ping`, which is the same name as the .NET class you are instantiating.

```
Partial Class Ping
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

Elsewhere in your code, you try to use the .NET `Ping` class.

I know that this can cause issues in certain project types.

Try naming your page `PingPage` instead *.

**As well as the other suggestions here about Namespaces etc.*